# Android - paint.setShadowLayer Ignoring shadowColor

Tags: java, android, paint

I am facing issue with shadow color, setShadowLayer method is ignoring shadowColor (Here i specified Color.RED in my code) instead of setShadowLayer is taking paint color (Here Color.argb(255, 50, 153, 187)). Below is my paint settings and find attached image for reference, thanks[image]

```
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 50, 153, 187));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setShadowLayer(7.0f, 20.0f, 2.0f, Color.RED);
```

Comment: the shadowLayer works only if the hardware acceleration is disabled. Try adding `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
        }`

Comment: Great it works with your solution. Please add it in answer, It will be helpful for other people. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the shadowLayer works only it the hardware acceleration is disabled. Add

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { 
      setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint); 
}
```

and it should work